# How to run Node.js program from command line without word 'node'

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, npm

I am developing the Node.js package, which includes a command-line utility. Now [alacon.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/master/alacon.js) is located in the root of the package. To run this utility I have to use word `node` before the name of utility, like:

```
 node alacon 'SELECT * FROM CSV("mydata.csv") ORDER BY 2'
```

Could you help me, what should I change in the package to:

1.To run this utility without `node` word, like:

```
 alacon 'SELECT * FROM CSV("mydata.csv") ORDER BY 2'
```

2.To install this package globally and use the utility everywhere on computer:

```
 npm install -g alasql
 alacon 'SELECT 2*2'
```

In other words, how to create utility like Jison, Gulp and other Node.js similar packages with command-line programs.

I already add the `#!/usr/bin/env node` line to the top of the file, but unfortunately have no desired effect.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make the script executable `chmod a+x alacon`.

Then you should be able to run `./alacon 'SELECT * FROM CSV("mydata.csv") ORDER BY 2'`

If you wish to invoke the script without `./` then you will need to move it (or symlink it) to /usr/bin.

Alternatively - you could create an alias: `alias alacon="node alacon"`

Comment: Thank you! Do you know, how to change package for global installation?