# starting nodejs app with "./"

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a math project for my school and I can choose the technologies.
I worked 6 mouth in web with nodejs before and my school said I can choose nodejs to do the project.

But this is the problem.

The mark of my project depend on how many test my code pass trough the automatic tests and so the robot who lunch the test only use ./my_app.js and not "node my_app.js"

I can't find any solution online to this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: What is this "robot"? How does it execute the JavaScript files?

Comment: Well I push my code on github and a robot only use ./projectname 12 14 for exemple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Node.js program from command line without word 'node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483592/how-to-run-node-js-program-from-command-line-without-word-node)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Linux or macOS.

If this is your my_app.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('Hello world');
```

Note the first line, which is what makes this possible.

You can execute it both ways:

```
$ node my_app.js
Hello world

$ chmod +x my_app.js
$ ./my_app.js
Hello world
```

You can also pass command-line arguments just as you would in the first mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot It's what I needed !